# Mqsql error Query was empty

Tags: php, database

```
$username="N/A";
$password="N/A";
$database="N/A";
$host="N/A";
$dbConn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
or die("Could not connect: " + mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $dbConn)
or die("Could not find database: " + mysql_error());


$txt = "<table align=\"center\">";
    $txt .= "<tr><td>KeyCode</td><td>Date</td><td>Sold</td><td>Email</td></tr>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `benkeys` where id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($query, $dbConn)
or die(mysql_error());
if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)) {
}

mysql_close($dbConn);
        $cal = "js_del_key('".$row["keycode"]."'); return false;";
        $txt .= "<tr><td>".$row['keycode']."</td><td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
        $txt .= "<td>".$row['sold']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td>";
        $txt .= "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"del\" value=\"DELETE\" onclick=\"".$cal."\"></td></tr>";

    $cal = "js_add_key(); return false;";
    $txt .= "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"46\" id=\"nkey\" /></td><td>".date("Y-m-d")."</td>";
    $txt .= "<td>N</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
    $txt .= "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"addkey\" value=\"ADD NEW\" onclick=\"".$cal."\"></td></tr>";
    $txt .= "</table>";
    mysql_close($link);
    return($txt);

function p_adm_del_key($key)
{
    $link = dbconnect();
    $sql = "delete from `benkeys` where `keycode`='".$key."' limit 1";
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($link);
    return(p_adm_list_keys());
}
function p_adm_add_key($key)
{
    $link = dbconnect();
    $sql = "insert into `benkeys` (`keycode`,`datum`,`sold`) values ('".$key."','".date("Y-m-d")."','N')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($link);
    return(p_adm_list_keys());
}
function dbconnect()    
{
    $link = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die("Could not select database: ".mysql_error());
    return($link);
}
?>
```

Iv looked over everything many times including the DataBase but I cant seem to find whats wrong I have no errors just "Query was empty" Could someone please help me out would be much appreciated Thanks.

My SQL root Is

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `benkeys` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Consider not using `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `benkeys` where id = 1";
 $res = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `benkeys` where id = 1";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $dbConn)
```

Comment: Now got this Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Comment: do u have a column called id in ur benkeys table in db?

Comment: no but im pretty sure its called "keycode"

Comment: then replace id with keycode if you intend to filter record on that column.

Comment: Ok i renamed id to keycode and now the page just shows nothing.

Comment: if u have phpmyadmin run this "SELECT * FROM `benkeys` where keycode = 1";  and if there is any record with that keycode.

Comment: yep $sql = "SELECT * FROM benkeys where keycode = 1";  Still same problem

Comment: so u don't have any record with keycode = 1; hence there is nothing wrong with query but the keycode = 1 has no records so u getting empty results.

Comment: Ill pm you my phpmyadmin details. wats ur email address?

Comment: Ok look if anyone see this I will even pay money to get this fixed

Comment: It is not a matter of money we are here to help each other but we are not able to understand your case still, we tried providing you every single chance of making a breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $`query` with $`sql`

```
$res = mysql_query($sql, $dbConn)
```